# Angular-Ui Bootstrap TabSet running on-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-tabset

I'm using Angular-Ui Bootstrap Tabset for AngularJS. I have 8 different tabs and all of them run a function when clicked. The activated tab is defined on the controller based on the object properties. The code is like this:

```
<tabset ng-if="paginaPronta">
  <tab heading="Histórico" active="activeTabs.historico" disabled="beforeNew" select="tabHistorico('html')">
    <div ng-include="includes.historico" class="row padding0"></div>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Pedido" active="activeTabs.pedido" select="tabPedido('html')">
    <div ng-include="includes.pedido" class="row padding0"></div>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Documentos" active="activeTabs.documentos" disabled="beforeNew" select="tabDocumentos('html')">
    <div ng-include="includes.documentos" class="row padding0"></div>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Posse" active="activeTabs.posse" disabled="beforeNew" select="tabPosse('html')">
    <div ng-include="includes.posse"></div>                
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Despesas" active="activeTabs.despesas" disabled="beforeNew" select="tabDespesas('html')">
    <div ng-include="includes.despesas" class="row padding0"></div>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Faturação" active="activeTabs.faturacao" select="tabFaturacao('html')">
    <div ng-include="includes.faturacao" class="row padding0"></div>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Anexos" select="tabAnexos('html')">
    <div ng-include="includes.anexos" class="row padding0"></div>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Relatório" active="activeTabs.relatorio" disabled="beforeNew" select="tabRelatorio('html')">
    <div ng-include="includes.relatorio"></div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

Everything works fine at beginning but, when I change the location to navigate to another page, all 8 tab functions are called (tabHistorico(), tabPedido(), tabPosse()...)

I'm not calling the functions in any other place, I put the 'html' in every function and them made a `console.log('tabHistorico: ' + phrase)` on the controller and it gets printted `tabHistorico: html`. So, I know that all tabs are activated, I can't figure out why...

Comment: What's about `html` parameter?

Comment: just to check if it was on the html that the function was called

Comment: could you make a fiddle or plunker?

Comment: are all tabs active? (activeTabs.historico == true......activeTabs.relatorio == true). You should also add some controller code in the question, there's not enough info now